# Navigation Controller design for multiple duplicate views

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm having a hard time understanding what approach I should take. I have a TableView controller with a list of questions, if you click a row it pushes a new `QuestionViewVontroller` that displays the `question`, `answers`, and `next button` (or done button). When a user clicks `next` I want to load the next question (from the tableview list) but I still want the navigation to work (back button will take you to TableView).

I'm starting to think I should keep the same `QuestionViewController` and just load in the question data. Is this right? Or should I use a modal view?

Comment: I would just load the next question data. Using a modal view could work, but just loading the next question into that view controller would be the simplest and maintain your ability to just pop that view controller off of the navigation stack back to the view controller containing the UITableView

Comment: Yea, that seems the simplest approach. I originally just passed the 'Question' managed object from core data. I guess I'll pass the set/array of 'Questions' now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Use the same QuestionViewController and just repopulate it, like you mentioned.
2. Push a new QuestionViewController and use custom back button that either pops to the root view controller or pops to a given view controller.

The code for both options in #2 is below, where "self" is the current view controller (your question controller).

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //this would pop to your UITableViewController, assuming it was the root

[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourTableViewControllerHere Animated:YES];  //this would work as long as you passed a reference to your UITableViewController to your question controllers
```

It's up to you how you choose to solve your issue.  However, if you decide to use the same QuestionViewController, include a catchy animation when importing the new question so the user knows what is happening and to make your app that much cooler :)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies how to do it with pushing a view. Performance-wise, does it matter how many VC's you are pushing/popping? I think it would be best to just repopulate the fields.

Comment: In theory, there "can" be memory issues if you push a ton of VCs. The memory for these VCs is not deallocated when they are not the top VC, so this could add up over time.  However, in many cases, this won't be an issue.  You would likely have to be pushing bunches and bunches of VCs, all with large background images or something else that would take up a bunch of memory, such as huge arrays of data.

Comment: As an added note... I'm not sure the format of your question/answer system, but a few things to consider: Can users answer questions out of order if they choose?  Do certain questions only appear based on answers to previous questions?  Can users go back and re-answer questions after already submitting an answer?  Based on the answer to these questions, you will better be able to decide how to present the questions.  Maybe in your presented question controller, you want a ScrollView that allows the user to scroll around and answer questions as they please... or maybe you don't.

Comment: The answer to all those questions in yes. I just implemented the reloading question instead of a new VC, seems to work fine. I will just have to add some logic to skip questions that are not needed but that isn't difficult.